# DB2 query to get next available number in table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with few columns and I want to achieve the following functionality using DB2 query.
say for e.g. USR table has User ID column and Option ID column

```
USER ID         OPTION ID
1               1
1               5
1               22
1               100    
1               999
```

I want to write a query and result should be next available number in sequence.

So when the first time query will be executed, it should return me the next 
available option ID as 2, so user will enter #2, so DB would have now

```
USER ID  OPTION ID
1         1  
1         2  
1         5  
1        22  
1        100      
1        999
```

so now when the query will be executed, it will show me available Option ID as 3. 
Can somebody help to get the optimized query to get the correct results?

Comment: In all honesty, you're probably better off re-creating the table with `option_id` being created as an auto-generated column, or being backed by a `SEQUENCE` object.  Any solution that anticipates _writing_ the results to the table in a concurrent (multi-user) environment basically needs to lock the table (or potentially just the section for `user_id = 1`), which will become a bottle-neck.... Are option ids uniquer per user-id, or for the entire table?

Comment: I am not writing into table. Query will return auto suggest option for user to use into the screen which will be the output of query. Yes, Option ID are unique per user and not for the table. So I will have where clause to use the UserID.

Comment: Nope, that's still the same problem; if you don't lock it, then somebody could enter the same value (even per user - what happens if people share accounts?).  In fact, it's a bad idea to show users table ids _to begin with_; these sorts of ids should be completely transparent to the user.  What is it you're actually doing?

Comment: Hi,
I am trying to help user to show the possible next available number and we have duplicate check, so if somebody (concurrent user) will also populate the same number but the user who submits first will get that assigned number and other user will duplicate message and this query will again auto suggest the possible next available number.
I am trying to auto suggest user with poosible available number which user can change in UI.

Comment: Dont want to have auto increment on option ID because user still can choose the number he wants as per business requirement.

Comment: ... Then the number isn't important, and you _really_ don't need to expose this to the user.  Besides which, even your duplicates checks will have wacky concurrency implications.  Although, `option_id` probably ought to be pre-assigned anyways (so `5` is always 'bought extended care package', or whatever).  You're attempting to make the user fill the role of the DB engine, which is dangerous, error-prone, and pointless; that's why they were written in the first place.  What is the conceptual 'entity' you're dealing with, **not** the actual _table record_.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that I think that exposing `option_id` to the user is a terrible idea, business requirement or no.  Surrogate id's like this are meant to be completely hidden from the end user ('natural' keys, like credit-card numbers, obviously have to be exposed, but still shouldn't be dictated in *this* manner).
The following should work on any version of DB2:

```
SELECT a.optionid + :nextIncrement as next_value                     
FROM Usr as a                          
LEFT JOIN Usr as b                
       ON b.userid = a.userid                 
          AND b.optionid = a.optionid + :nextIncrement        
WHERE a.userid = :userId      
      AND b.userid IS NULL               
ORDER BY a.optionid ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

(statement run against a local table on my iSeries instance, with host variables replaced)

Again, I *strongly* recommend you **not** use this, and see about getting the business requirement changed.

Comment: Any version of DB2? Doesn't seem to work on DB2/AIX64 10.5.5. Says "exception" is an unexpected token; expected tokens may include "<space>"...

Comment: @ADTC - ...fixed.  At the time I tended to forget non-iSeries versions existed or had different implementations.  I still don't recommend this overall, though.